# Is Ubuntu still planning on coming out with a phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Did the Edge phone fail? And if they do come out with a phone, will it have the same specs as the original?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Edge is dead, however it has been announced [that Ubuntu will be shipped on a phone](http://www.geek.com/news/a-ubuntu-phone-will-finally-go-on-sale-next-year-1610437/) in select European markets. It’s a 5.4-inch screen powered by a MediaTek octa-core processor, with 2GB of RAM, a 418ppi display, 20MP camera, LTE radio, and a retail price of around $350.

Answer (score 1):

Edge has failed to be produced. As of May 2015:

If you live in EU you can buy now BQ Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu Edition here http://www.bq.com/gb/aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition It has lower specification than Ubuntu Edge

Or if you live in China you can buy Meizu MX4
http://store.meizu.com/product/mx4_mon.html#4-1-4 This is high end phone and some of it's parameters are even **better than original Ubuntu Edge** :-)

There are plans to sell ubuntu phones in other regions "soon".

Answer (score 0):

An official, Canonical-created/designed phone? No. The Ubuntu Edge, sad though it may be, is dead. Canonical/Ubuntu did not [receive the funding necessary](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/08/ubuntu-edge-fails-to-meet-mutli-million-dollar-goal-wont-be-made).

*However*, Bq and Meizu have both stepped forward and said that they are going to produce Ubuntu phones - with Bq [actually planning to release their Aquaris e4.5 handset in Europe in February of 2015](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/12/bq-ubuntu-phone-launches-in-europe-this-february).

Sadly, this only applies to Europe as of yet - there has been no information regarding the sale of these devices in America.

Another, although not official, device that is supposed to support Ubuntu for Phones [is a *modular* device from Vsenn - not unlike Google's Project Ara](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/12/modular-smartphone-ara-rival-ubuntu-touch).

Comment: Does the new phones have the same "Saphire Glass" and the "120 GB" like the Edge specs had?

Comment: @Marcus Well, Bq is simply taking one of their Android phones (Aquaris E4.5) and shipping it with Ubuntu instead of Android - so any specs on the Android version will be the same.